# SSRS 2012 - Range Chart: How to Change Month Interval to Quarter and Grouping Vertical axis?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am developing SSRS range chart report in 2012 by following http://pnarayanaswamy.blogspot.in/2012/12/ssrs-2008-r2-range-bar-chart-gantt.html link, Now I have a problem with month headers and grouping range chart.

1. I am giving Label Intervaltype = months and Label Interval = 3 and LabelFormat = "MMM". It is showing month name for each 3 months. I want to convert it to corresponding months quarter format.Like it has to show Q1 Q2 Q3 for each year.
2. My left side range chart repeating the group names for each row of projects. I want to truncate the group by only one name for each group. When I tried with group category by Project_Group, the adjustment between group chart and details chart are not matching. For example, "Control Level group needs to be displayed only once instead of 3 times, meanwhile all 3 projects remains same in details chart, and the spaces needs to be remain same till next level"

Below is my table structure,

**Project   -----------   Project_Group**

MAC -----------     Backbone

FT  -----------Building

MA  -----------Control Level

MACH----------- Control Level

MIC -----------Control Level

EE  -----------Embedded

EC  -----------Embedded

Emb -----------Embedded

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the grouping issue by using Series Groups and writing expression in series label properties "=IIF(Previous(Fields!Project_Group.Value) = Fields!Project_Group.Value,"",Fields!Project_Group.Value)"...

Can anybody help me to show the quarter in x axis from month?